# Inverter linha com coluna em uma matriz?

Tags: c, matriz

> Faça um programa que gere aleatoriamente 20 números inteiros na faixa de 0 a 999 e preencha uma matriz de tamanho 5 x 4. Mostre a matriz, em seguida mostre a matriz transposta (inverter linha com coluna).

Eu já consegui preencher a matriz com números aleatórios só que não sei transpostar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
  int i, j, matriz[5][4], matriz5[4][5];
  srand(time(NULL));

   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
           matriz[i][j] = rand()%999;

   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
           printf(" %d ",matriz[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para achar a transposta da matriz basta inverter os indices na atribuição dos valores, a linha vai para a coluna e vice-versa.

Exemplificando no seu código, criando a matriz transposta em `matriz5`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        matriz5[j][i] = matriz[i][j];
        //      ^--^-----------^--^
    }
}
```

Tenha depois atenção no momento de mostrar pois os limites de linhas e colunas também estarão invertidos:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
//              ^--- 
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    //             ^---
        printf(" %d ", matriz5[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/5IBo4y)